# How I can add key/value to the object in object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have such array with objects:

```
[
  {age: 20, data: {money: 20}},
  {age: 30, data: {money: 30}},
  {age: 40, data: {money: 40}}
]
```

How can I add to every object the filed `id` to the object data? Id can be the same in every object.

Expected result:

```
{ageL 20, data: {money: 20, id: 1}}
```

Comment: How are you getting the value for the id properties?

Comment: @Teemu just random number, I think it doesn't matter. I just need to know how I can add value to obj.data

Comment: `arr.forEach(i => i.data.id = ...)`…?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let myArray = [
  {age: 20, data: {money: 20}},
  {age: 30, data: {money: 30}},
  {age: 40, data: {money: 40}}
]
let myID = [
  1,
  2,
  3
]

myArray.map((obj, index) => {
  obj.data['id'] = myID[index]
})

console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: Don't use `map` if you're not going to create a new array.

Comment: To expand on Teemu's point. Map is a functional programming construct, and one of the core ideas is that calling functions do not cause side-effects. A map is supposed to map an input list into an output list with a one-to-one mapping between the elements. Use a more imperative construct like `.forEach()` for situations where you are causing side-effects.